# Is the API being called before I call it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am trying to create a UI for an email validator. I am using an API that I can only make one call to per second. Below is my code so far - VERY BASIC. I barely got started. But when I try running it, it throws multiple errors with the same error message saying there are "Too many requests" and that I "have exceeded the requests per second allowed". Is there a reason why it is telling me that I am exceeding my call limit? I am definitely not calling it more than once per second.

```
function App() {

  const [result, setResult] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    validateEmail('')
  }, [])
  
  async function validateEmail(email){
    const response = await fetch(`https://emailvalidation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=${API_KEY}&email=${email}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setResult(data);
  }

  validateEmail('POOKIEWOOKIE.com')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{result}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: validateEmail calls setState, which causes a rerender, which valls validateEmail again. This loops forever.

Comment: It does that even when I take out the setResult(data) and only have the console.log(data) as the output of the async function. What about in this case?

Comment: useEffect is the combination of componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount. In the above sample code, first the validateEmail('POOKIEWOOKIE.com') function call happens and then same function is again called from useEffect callback with empty parameters. After the each successful function call, the result state is updated which in turns call the callback of useEffect (which in turn calls validateEmail) and this continues infinitely. But if the setResult(data) is taken out then function call happens only twice. [Playground](https://playcode.io/1688411)